# Macro For MULTIPLE Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have many columns that must be pasted into another tab to perform a calculation.  The macro grabs data from Column CH and pastes it into the Calculation sheet.  Grabs the calculated field and pastes that below CH172 on the production tab.  I want to perform this routine for subsequent columns (CI, CJ, etc.)

```
Sub MonthlyCost()
    Range("CH147:CH172").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("1.2.1.1 Calculation").Select
    Range("J10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("W63").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("1.2.1.1 Production").Select
    Range("CH174").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the range (row count) the same for the other columns?

Comment: Have you run into a problem trying to do this?  What is it?

Comment: Yes, the row count for all other columns is the same. When I select column CI and run the macro, the macro performs the operation on CH again.

Comment: I'm researching how to perform a loop, this may be my solution

Comment: what is the range you want to copy?  CH and CI, but where does it end?   Or does the end column change?

Comment: Also when copying CI147:CI172, is J10 and W63 each increased by a column? Meaning CI147:CI172 gets copied to K10 and you copy X63 to CI174 (so on and so forth for subsequent columns)

Comment: J10 and W63 will remain in place.  They are on a different tab, J10 is where each column is pasted to perform a calculation, W63 is the grand total which is copied and pasted to the Production tab.  I will always copy the same number of cells from CH, CI, and so on. CH147:CH172 represents data from Dec-Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly tested and runs w/o error on my end.  I'm pretty sure this will do what you want.  If not, please let me know and I'll take another stab at it:

```
Sub MonthlyCost()

Dim columnStart As Long
Dim columnsToCopy As Long
Dim columnEnd As Long
Dim i As Long

columnsToCopy = 5

columnStart = 86 ' this is column CH
columnEnd = columnStart + columnsToCopy - 1 ' this will loop from column CH {column 1 of the columnsToCopy} to column CL {column 5 of the columnsToCopy}


For i = columnStart To columnEnd
    Range(Sheets("1.2.1.1 Production").Cells(147, i), Sheets("1.2.1.1 Production").Cells(172, i)).Copy
    Sheets("1.2.1.1 Calculation").Range("J10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("1.2.1.1 Calculation").Range("W63").Copy
    Sheets("1.2.1.1 Production").Cells(174, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i

End Sub
```

This can probably be cleaned up w/ a few using statements or setting the sheets to a variable, but this should hopefully get you started.

Good luck and let me know how it turns out!

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line: Range(Sheets("1.2.1.1 Production").Cells(147, i), Sheets("1.2.1.1 Production").Cells(172, i)).Copy  (Run Time error '9' - subscript out of range)

Comment: @user3388834 I'm not getting an error on my end.  Are you sure your sheet is named "1.2.1.1 Production" and not something like "1.2.1.1 Production " (note the trailing space).  That error leads me to believe that the sheet name doesn't exist as you have it typed.

Comment: Yes! you are correct Sous!  This is exactly what I needed.  thank you for your help, you've saved me a lot of future work!

Comment: @user3388834 Hurray! Glad it worked out for you!  Feel free to mark it the "accepted" answer and / or upvote it so that other people know it was helpful.